# Addition of more than 30 digits

Tags: java

I am doing this project in java that takes two integer values (max of 30 digits) and add them together. Since I am not allowed to use Big Integer, or other class, I thought of taking them as a string then convert them to integers. Here's what I have so far:

```
import java.util.*;
public class Test{
    public static void  main(String[] args){

    System.out.print("Input 1: ");
    char[] firstInteger = myInput();
    System.out.print("Input 2: ");  
    char[] secondInteger = myInput();

    int[] num1 = char2Integer(firstInteger);
    int[] num2 = char2Integer(secondInteger);
    sum(num1, num2);
    }
    public static char[] myInput(){
        String numbers;
        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
        numbers = input.nextLine();

        while(numbers.length() > 30){
            System.out.println("Please input valid integers with digits less than 30");
            numbers = input.nextLine();
        }return numbers.toCharArray();
    }
    public static int[] char2Integer(char[] integer){
        int[] numbers = new int[integer.length+1];
        int j=integer.length-1;

        for (int i = numbers.length-1; i>0 ; i--){
            if(j>-1){
                numbers[i] = (int)(integer[j]-'0');
                j--;
            }
        }return numbers;
    }
    public static void sum(int[] num1, int[] num2){
        int[] sum = new int[num1.length];

        for (int i = sum.length-1 ; i> 0; i--){
            sum[i] += num1[i]+num2[i];

            if(sum[i] >= 10){
                sum[i] = sum[i]%10;
                sum[i-1]++;
            }
        }
        for (int i = 0; i< sum.length; i++)
            System.out.print(sum[i]);
    }
}
```

My problem now is: when adding arrays of different lengths, I get weird answers.
(Adding arrays of the same length works fine.)
For example:

```
input 1 = 50
input 2 = 500
output = 100
```

and

```
input 1 = 50
input 2 = 5
output = java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
```

I tried reversing the arrays then add them up, but I get an outOfBoundsException : -1.
I also thought of converting the shorter array to the same length as the longer array but that would take lots of lines in my code. Thank you for your help. I will take all positive/negative suggestions.

Answer (score 2):

Check this code for sum function.

```
public static void sum(int[] num1, int[] num2){
    int num1len = num1.length;
    int num2len = num2.length;

    int[] sum= new int[num1len>num2len?num1len:num2len];

    for (int i = sum.length-1 ; i> 0; i--){
        if(num1len>0)
            sum[i] += num1[--num1len];

        if(num2len>0)
            sum[i] += num2[--num2len];

        if(sum[i] >= 10){
            sum[i] = sum[i]%10;
            sum[i-1]++;
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i< sum.length; i++)
        System.out.print(sum[i]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

pad the shorted number with 0's so it's the same length as the longer one.

e.g.

```
input 1 = 50
input 2 = 5
```

should be interpreted as 50 + 05

Answer (score 0):

Yes because of this line

```
 sum[i] += num1[i]+num2[i];
```

if one of the array's has more length than the other, you deal with them as they have the same length always

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is in sum method where you are not taking into consideration about the length of two input and even lsb number 1 getting summed up with lsb of number 2:

```
  public static void sum(int[] num1, int[] num2){
      int[] sum = new int[num1.length > num2.length ? num1.length : num2.length];//allocate for whoever is having more number of characters in input.

      for (int i = num1.length-1, j = num2.length - 1, k = sum.length - 1 ; i> 0 || j > 0; i--, j--, k--){//take three variables one for each
          sum[k] += num1[i]+num2[j];

          if(sum[k] >= 10){
              sum[k] = sum[k]%10;
              sum[k-1]++;
          }
      }
      for (int i = 0; i< sum.length; i++)
          System.out.print(sum[i]);
  }
```

Comment: apparently, i don't know how to use [array.length  > array2.length ? array.length : ] notation... can you enlighten me?

Comment: we call it as ternary operation. it works like ((some condition) ? if condition holds true then execute me : else execute me).